# 2D numerical integration with infinite limit (C++)

Tags: c++, quadrature, integration

In order to integrate a two dimensional function of the form

$$\int_{1}^\infty \int_{-\sqrt{x^2-1}}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}} e^{-x} \rm{d}y \rm{d}x,$$

I have been attempting to use the following code (written in C++) taken mostly from the Numerical Recipes book which calls a gaussian quadrature routine for the integration:

```
 static float xsav;
 static float (*nrfunc)(float,float);

 float quad2d(float (*func)(float, float), float x1, float x2)
 {
     float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
     float f1(float x);

     nrfunc=func;
     return qgaus(f1,x1,x2); 
 }

 float f1(float x) 
 {
     float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float a, float b); 
     float f2(float y);
     float yy1(float),yy2(float);

     xsav=x;
     return qgaus(f2,yy1(x),yy2(x)); 
 }

 float f2(float y)  
 {
     return (*nrfunc)(xsav,y);
 }
```

This code works fine for two dimensional integrals with finite limits, but fails as the outer limit is taken to infinity. To account for this, I have attempted to use a change of variables:

```
#define FUNC(x) ((*funk)(-log(x))/(x))

float qgaus(float (*funk)(float), float aa, float bb)
{
    int j;
    float xr,xm,dx,s,a,b;

    b=exp(-aa); 
    a=0.0;

    static float x[]={0.0,0.1488743389,0.4333953941,
        0.6794095682,0.8650633666,0.9739065285};
    static float w[]={0.0,0.2955242247,0.2692667193, 
        0.2190863625,0.1494513491,0.0666713443};

    xm=0.5*(b+a); 
    xr=0.5*(b-a);
    s=0;
    for (j=1;j<=5;j++)
    {
        dx=xr*x[j];
        s += w[j]*(FUNC(xm+dx)+FUNC(xm-dx)); 
    }
    return s *= xr; 
}


float f(float x, float y)
{
    float a = exp(-x);
    return a;
}

float yy1(float x)
{
    float y = -sqrt(x*x-1);
    return y;   
}

float yy2(float x)
{
    float y = sqrt(x*x-1);
    return y;
}



static float xsav;
static float (*nrfunc)(float, float);

float quad2d(float (*func)(float, float), float x1, float x2)
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float aa, float bb);
    float f1(float x);

    nrfunc=func;
    float t = qgaus(f1,x1,x2);
    return t;
}

float f1(float x)
{
    float qgaus(float (*func)(float), float aa, float bb);
    float f2(float y);
    float yy1(float);
    float yy2(float);

    xsav=x;
    float r = qgaus(f2,yy1(x),yy2(x));
    return r;
}

float f2(float y) 
{
    float k = (*nrfunc)(xsav,y);
    return k;
}

int main ()
{
    float z;
    z = quad2d(f, 1.0, 20.0);
    cout << z << endl;
}
```

but this still doesn't give the right answer. It should be $2 \times \rm{BesselK}[1,1] \approx 1.20381$, but instead gives 2.15501.

Any suggestions on how I could modify this code to account for the infinite limit would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: afaik, there are two standard methods of dealing with such integrals: (1) use a variable transformation that maps your infinite interval to a finite one, or (2) use a special quadrature scheme that can deal with (semi-) infinite integration intervals, such as [Gauss-Laguerre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Laguerre_quadrature).

Comment: You may want to look at one of the following posts: [this one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/how-can-i-approximate-an-improper-integral) or [this one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19895/improper-numerical-integral)

Comment: That change of variables looks slightly dubious to me, can you post the whole code please? Moreover, can you specify *how* it fails, what the actual output is? (It can fail in different ways, and you're not being specific enough there.) Whatever the reason, try your code first on a simpler testcase, such as $\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}x$—it will make your problem easier to diagnose.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $\int_1^\infty\int_0^1 x^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: I tested the code I posted above with the function you suggested and it outputs 5.03506 instead of 1. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: You need to use the username with a @ before it to notify people. For example: @Kirill

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard way to deal with infinite limits in integrals.  This is explained nicely in the [README of the `cubature` package](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature#infinite-intervals) (which you should use for low-but-multi-dimensional integration).

> ## Infinite intervals
>
> Integrals over infinite or semi-infinite intervals is possible by a change of variables. This is best illustrated in one dimension.
>
> To compute an integral over a semi-infinite interval, you can perform the change of variables $x=a+t/(1-t)$:
>
> $$\int_a^\infty f(x) dx = \int_0^1 f\biggl(a+\frac{t}{1-t}\biggr) \frac{1}{(1-t)^2} dt.$$
>
> For an infinite interval, you can perform the change of variables $x=t/(1 -
>  t^2)$:
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 f\biggl(\frac{t}{1-t^2}\biggr) \frac{1+t^2}{(1-t^2)^2} dt.$$
>
> Note the Jacobian factors multiplying $f(\dots)$ in both integrals, and also that the limits of the $t$ integrals are different in the two cases.
>
> In multiple dimensions, one simply performs this change of variables on each dimension separately, as desired, multiplying the integrand by the corresponding Jacobian factor for each dimension being transformed.

---

In your specific case where you can easily work out the $y$ integration by hand, I'd use the GSL package to compute the integral with the existing quadrature package, which can deal with infinite intervals.

Using
$$\int_{-\sqrt{x^2-1}}^{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \exp(-x) dy = 2 \exp(-x) \sqrt{x^2-1}$$
one then has

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

double f(double x, void * params)
{
  return 2*exp(-x)*sqrt(x*x-1);
}

int main()
{
  gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(100);
  double result, error;

  gsl_function F;
  F.function = &f;

  gsl_integration_qagiu(&F, 1, 1e-7, 1e-7, 100, w, &result, &error);

  printf ("result          = %.18f\n", result);
  printf ("estimated error = %.18f\n", error);
  printf ("intervals       = %zu\n", w->size);

  gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);
}
```